# C++ Rebuilding Singly Linked List Links

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm attempting to build a `priority queue` using a `singly linked list`. The idea is that I always store the minimum `int x` inside my `Node* head`. When the `deleteMin()` method is called. It should return the minimum value (`head->x`), and also update the head to the next lowest value in the list.

The problem that I seem to be having is updating the links once a new `lowestNode` has been found.

SLList.hpp

```
const int deleteMin() {
    int returnVal = this->head->x;

    // we need to find the next lowest in the list and update our head, then relink the list.
    // first update our head to the next of the current head
    this->head = this->head->next;
    cout << "head now: " << this->head->x << endl;

    // iterate through our nodes searching for a smaller value
    Node* currentNode       = this->head;
    Node* nextNode          = NULL;
    Node* lowestNode        = NULL;
    Node* prevNode          = NULL;
    // Node* prevHead          = NULL;
    // Node* nextHead          = NULL;

    while(currentNode != NULL) {
        if (currentNode->next->x < this->head->x) {
            nextNode = currentNode->next->next;
            cout << "nextNode: " << nextNode->x << endl;
            lowestNode = currentNode->next;
            cout << "lowestNode: " << lowestNode->x << endl;
            prevNode = currentNode;
            cout << "prevNode: " << prevNode->x << endl;
            // prevHead = this->head;
            // cout << "prevHead: " << prevHead->x << endl;
            // nextHead = this->head->next;
            // cout << "nextHead: " << nextHead->x << endl;

            // update links
            lowestNode->next    = this->head->next;
            currentNode         = this->head;
            currentNode->next   = nextNode;
            this->head          = lowestNode;
        } else {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
    }

    // decrement the size
    this->_size--;
    // return the minVal
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: how as the list *built* ? if it was maintained as sorted from inception, this seems to be a ton of work for what should be a simple head-pop. And i'm curious about you potential behavior if the list is *empty* (i.e. `head` is nullptr) or has a single entry (where things like `head->next->x` will spell potential doom).

Comment: the list is not sorted, but is intended to implement the same properties as a priority queue. This means that the `head` of my list is prioritized to always contain the lowest value for `int x`, the rest of the list remains unsorted.

Comment: So... you're basically moving the sort action to pop-time rather than push-time? Either way the expense is still there and is unavoidable. I'm just trying to think of the case where list-scanning at pop-time is more advantageous than at push-time for a generic linked list. Regardless. It's all about the pointers pointers pointing to the nodes; pointer-to-pointer work should make this easier, I would think.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your right. My list does actually get sorted as a `pop` occurs. Thanks a lot for your input. This actually did help me. I will post a solution once I finished testing, and would appreciate any input. The only reason that I did the sorting on the pop is that is how the textbook I am using explained it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(currentNode != NULL && currentNode->next!=NULL) //here you need check for currectNode->next also for NULL condition
 {
    if (currentNode->next->x < this->head->x) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next->next;
        cout << "nextNode: " << nextNode->x << endl;
        lowestNode = currentNode->next;
        cout << "lowestNode: " << lowestNode->x << endl;
        //here storing previous node is of no use except for debugging
        prevNode = currentNode;
        cout << "prevNode: " << prevNode->x << endl;


        // update links- here you need to first remove the lowest node from    its postion
        currentNode->next=nextNode;
        //and then add lowest node a the front
        lowestNode->next    = this->head->next;
        this->head          = lowestNode;
    } else {
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I realized was that depending on where the node that contains the lowest `int x`. If `head` is directly linked a lower node, then the relinking needed to be a little different than if a lower node was found in the middle of the list.

```
#ifndef SLLIST_H
#define SLLIST_H

using namespace std;

class SLList
{
    struct Node {
        int x;
        Node *next;
    };

    private:
        int _size;

    public:
        Node* head; // used to store minimum value of a Node's x
        Node* tail; 

        SLList() :
        _size(0),
        head(NULL),
        tail(NULL) {

        }

        int size() const {
            return this->_size;
        }

        const int add (const int x) {
            // create new node
            Node* newNode = new Node();
            newNode->x = x;

            if (this->_size == 0) {
                this->head          = newNode;
                this->tail          = newNode;
            } else {
                if (newNode->x < this->head->x) {
                    // update head to new lowest and relink nodes
                    newNode->next       = this->head;
                    this->head          = newNode;
                } else {
                    this->tail->next    = newNode;
                    this->tail          = newNode;
                }
            }

            // update list size
            this->_size++;
            return x;
        }

        const int deleteMin() {
            if (this->_size == 0) return -1;

            int returnVal = this->head->x;
            cout << "removing min val: " << returnVal << endl;

            // we need to find the next lowest in the list and update our head, then relink the list.
            // first update our head to the next of the current head
            this->head = this->head->next;

            // iterate through our nodes searching for a smaller value
            Node* currentNode       = this->head;
            Node* lowestNode        = NULL;

            for(int i = 0; i < this->_size - 1; i++) {
                if (currentNode->next->x < this->head->x) {
                    lowestNode      = currentNode->next;

                    if (currentNode == this->head) { 
                        cout << "current->next is next to head" << endl;
                        // only need to update 2 nodes
                        this->head->next = currentNode->next->next;
                        lowestNode->next = this->head;
                        this->head       = lowestNode;

                        currentNode = currentNode->next;
                    } else {
                        // update three nodes
                        cout << "current->next has neighbours" << endl;
                        // Example scenario
                        // 3 // nextTo5
                        // 5 // nextTo4
                        // 4 // nextTo2
                        // 2 // nextToNull

                        // == turns into ==

                        // 2 // nextTo5
                        // 5 // nextTo4
                        // 4 // nextTo3
                        // 3 // nextToNull
                        lowestNode->next = this->head->next;
                        currentNode->next   = this->head; 
                        this->head = lowestNode;

                        currentNode = currentNode->next;
                    }
                } else {
                    currentNode = currentNode->next;
                }
            }

            // decrement the size
            this->_size--;
            // return the minVal
            return returnVal;
        }

        const void printList() const {
            Node* tmp = this->head;
            cout << "printing list... " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < this->_size; i++) {
                cout << tmp->x << endl;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }

};

#endif  // SLLIST_H
```

Perhaps I should actually use the `tail` somehow, but currently, I don't really use it for much.